# map all unspecified subdomains to primary domain in with Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using the following Amazon AWS services:  Elastic Beanstalk, EC2 (load balancer) and Route 53.  I've specified a primary domain in Route 53 but have not yet set up any sub domains.  I'd like for all unspecified subdomains to resolve to the primary domain.  E.g.:

```
cat.example.com -> example.com
cow.example.com -> example.com
```

Where neither 'cat' nor 'cow' subdomains have been specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, add a new record set, put "*.yourdomain.com" and create a cname record to map it to yourdomain.com. Works like a charm.

That will get the IP address to resolve properly - you'll may still need to configure your website to bind to those addresses as well.

Comment: Thanks.  Would that override if any other subdomains are defined?

Comment: No.  Defined subdomains (including future ones) will work as expected.